# CUDA mathfunctions.hpp compiler error on Mac OS: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type

Tags: macos, cuda

I tried to compile the code from https://github.com/wilicc/gpu-burn using the following Makefile. It is a GPU burner using CUDA and my Mac indeed has the GT750M.

```
  1 CUDAPATH=/usr/local/cuda
  2
  3 # Have this point to an old enough gcc (for nvcc)
  4 GCCPATH=/usr/bin/clang
  5
  6 NVCC=nvcc
  7 CCPATH=${GCCPATH}/bin
  8
  9 drv:
 10         PATH=${PATH}:.:${CCPATH}:${PATH} ${NVCC} -I${CUDAPATH}/include -arch=compute_30 -ptx compare.cu -o compare.ptx
 11         g++ -O3 -Wno-unused-result -I${CUDAPATH}/include -c gpu_burn-drv.cpp
 12         g++ -o gpu_burn gpu_burn-drv.o -O3 -lcuda -L${CUDAPATH}/lib64 -L${CUDAPATH}/lib -Wl,-rpath=${CUDAPATH}/lib64 -Wl,-rpath=${CUDAPATH}/lib -lcublas -lcudart -o gpu_burn
```

But I received eight compile errors stating that "`/usr/local/cuda/include/crt/math_functions.hpp(xxx): error: cannot overload functions distinguished by return type alone`".

I installed the latest CUDA 10.1.105 on my mac, and compile the code by using **Clang**, but it doesn't work. If I switch back to **gcc**, the errors are still there.

gcc --version: Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)

Comment: Actually, it happens to me even I try to compile the sample code from the CUDA 
driver official installation guide. It seems a common issue to me.

Comment: I assume you're on Mojave? gcc is symlinked to clang, so unless you intentionally installed gcc and configured it, you're still just using clang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround to this is to simply edit `math_functions.hpp` (and also `math_functions.h` in my case) and comment out the offending lines.